# limit the items to show in HTML drop down list when it opens

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have 10 items in drop down and want to display only first 5 when i open the drop down list and rest of the items should remain in scroll.

I have the following code to control the size in `JS`.

```
$(function(){
  $("#myList").click(function(){
    $(this).attr('size', '5');
  });
});
```

Setting the following in `HTML`...

```
<select size="5">
  <option value=""></option>
  ...
</select>
```

will make the drop down to always appear with 5 items as default and browsers may handle this their own way so i thought of doing it via `JS`.

The **problem** with this is it open with 5 items but did not close automatically as what a normal drop down does, until page get refreshed (obviously). Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the list so that it displays multiple items, and then only shows the selected when hover is removed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#mylist").hover(function(){

$(this).attr('size', '5');
},function(){
 $(this).removeAttr("size");   
});

});​
```

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/q2c9j/)

Answer (score 0):

However the accepted solution worked just fine but only for jQuery versions prior to **1.9** because [`hover` has been deprecated](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#quot-hover-quot-pseudo-event) from this version henceforth.

But you can use make the `hover()` and other deprecated features work using [jQuery migrate plugin](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) if you do not want to switch to a newer version.

An alternative solution for higher versions of `jQuery` i.e. v1.9 +

```
$(function(){
  $("#myList").on({
    mousedown: function(){
      $(this).attr('size', '5');
    },

    mouseleave: function(){
      $(this).removeAttr('size');
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a [**working DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/duworu/edit?html,js,output).